# Magento 2 City field not showing in cart for shipping estimation

Tags: magento2, layout

We have installed Shippit to calculate rates and it requires the City to be filled out for Australian addresses. This is fine in checkout.

However in the cart there is **no city** field showing, resulting in no calculation. How do I enable the city field to be present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

You should take a look at `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/LayoutProcessor.php`

[image]

So, we can enable it by using Plugin. There is a Plugin of DHL module: `vendor/magento/module-dhl/Model/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php`

Comment: Ahh perfect! I see isCityActive() was set to false by default. I've changed it to true and that's worked a treat!